# Surah Rahman - Does meaning of وَضَعَ changes in the two ayahs?

Tags: quran, tafseer, surat-ar-rahman

In Surah Rahman

[Verse 7](https://quran.com/55), Allah says

> وَالسَّمَاءَ رَفَعَهَا **وَوَضَعَ** الْمِيزَانَ
>
> And the heaven He raised and **imposed** the balance

But in the [Verse 10](https://quran.com/55), Allah says

> وَالْأَرْضَ **وَضَعَهَا** لِلْأَنَامِ
>
> And the earth He **laid [out]** for the creatures.

Are the words in bold not the same? If yes, does the meaning of the word change with context in Arabic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every single world in Arabic has many meanings, so it should be translated according to the situation and context where it is used. Mostly `وضع` used in these meanings

- to put
- to place
- to lay down
- modesty
- theme
- topic
- inventor

So every translator try to choose the meaning which fit best and give better and clear meaning of verse.

Answer (score 2):

Check in a dictionary like in [almaany وَضَع  ( فعل ):](https://www.almaany.com/en/dict/ar-en/%D9%88%D8%B6%D8%B9/) and you may find that the verb وَضَع may be used in the meaning of:

- to put
- to place (as in [18:49](http://legacy.quran.com/18/49) and [39:69](http://legacy.quran.com/39/69))
- to compose
- to establish (as in [3:96](http://legacy.quran.com/3/96))
- to create
- to give birth (as in [3:36](http://legacy.quran.com/3/36))
- to lower
- to humiliate
- to remove ([94:2](http://legacy.quran.com/94/2))

**A few words about the verses**

In verse ([55:7](http://legacy.quran.com/55/7)) maybe the translation imposed is a bit bad, a better fit might be established or placed it down, if we interpret it as the justice which came down from heaven (Allah) to earth, as the balance here refer's to justice (as other translations show).

In verse ([55:10](http://legacy.quran.com/55/10)) maybe here laid-out is a good fit, as the earth was made for humans and other creatures as a perfect place to live.